# Using SentencePiece as a command

Tags: command-line, pip, nlp

I need to use Google's SentencePiece from

[SentencePiece Github](https://github.com/google/sentencepiece)

I have installed it via pip and I would like to run the example command to train a model like

```
spm_train --input=<input> --model_prefix=<model_name> --vocab_size=8000 --character_coverage=1.0 --model_type=<type>
```

However I get `spm_train: command not found` does that mean I need to install C++ version from the github ?

Also, how can I know when a pip install will allow me to use the terminal command described in README ?

Because when I install a very similar program [Sennrich BPE](https://github.com/rsennrich/subword-nmt) I just need to install via pip and then run the command in my terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subword-nmt` creates a script [subword-nmt](https://github.com/rsennrich/subword-nmt/blob/18a5c87046d15290a1b7d947449052aa6d2b47cc/setup.py#L33) when installed. Python `sentencepiece` doesn't install any scripts, it's only a Python wrapper for the C++ library.

To execute `spm_*` scripts from `sentencepiece` you certainly have to install C++ version.

Comment: So is that subword-nmt script what we call an entry point for the program ? Your answer cleared the situation for me, thanks

Comment: The script declared as `subword_nmt.subword_nmt:main` so Python calls [function `main()` from `subword_nmt/subword_nmt.py`](https://github.com/rsennrich/subword-nmt/blob/18a5c87046d15290a1b7d947449052aa6d2b47cc/subword_nmt/subword_nmt.py#L22).